# Does a dispenser tether cloaked spies?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-spy, tf2-engineer

I know that, as a cloaked spy, I can recharge my watch from a dispenser. In fact, a L3 dispenser can recharge my watch faster than it drains. However, I know that dispensers display a glowing tether to units that they are resupplying. If I cloak next to (or on top of) an enemy dispenser, will I get tethered and thus be revealed to detail-oriented Engies and Pyros?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**No**, cloaked spies will not be tethered by dispensers.

It's the same mechanic as to whether medics can attach medigun beams to cloaked spies. They can't, and I know flickering from being bumped doesn't change it.

Most special effects are hidden while cloaked, with notable exceptions being milk/jarate/blood/water drips and fire.

Comment: Will the tether be shown if I bump into the spy, showing the silhouette?  Also does the tether disappear at the start or end of the cloaking process?  I'm pretty sure I've gotten spies because of the tether.

Comment: It's the same mechanic as to whether medics can attach medigun beams to cloaked spies.  They can't, and I know flickering from being bumped doesn't change it.

Comment: @Luck What about when you're not cloaked?  Does the tether connect to you?